# how to determine HTML load time vs. DOM load time

Tags: html, performance, browser

I have a page which is taking some time to load which uses the Mixitup plugin.  I can use Chrome's inspector to see how long it takes for the DOM to load.  However, I would also like to know how long the actual HTML code takes to load (i.e from the first <html> string to the last </html> string.  How can I do this?

Also, is there a command line using `wget` or `cURL` which might do this easily?

Answer (score 1):

In Google Chrome press **F12** on the window you want to monitor, go to the **Timeline** tab and mark the **JS Profile** and the **Paint** check-boxes and reload the page. This should capture the rendering process. After the page is fully loaded press stop and look at the results, they should tell you how much time every step of the rendering took.